# Virtual File system that joins dir trees into one (UnionFS)

Tags: linux, filesystems

Linux is preferable, but that would be nice if there's a Windows solution :)

---

I have **two USB HDDs**, and each has category folders: e.g. "Music" and "Video" - kinda archive. Later, when they're full, i will add more devices.

Is there a way to **join the two dir trees** (from different devices) into one virtual filesystem? So that i can access its root, and see all files joined into one tree?

Comment: Are you looking to cluster them, or just have them mounted as different subdirectories?

Comment: Smth like clustering into one big virtual joined filesystem, that is called "union mount"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **UnionFS stuff** might help

Some information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS), it allows you to overlay multiple mounts and directories onto one another.

Comment: No worries. It is actually pretty nifty. I use it sometimes for odd source-code management practice :)

Answer (score 1):

Linux have this already. You can do e.g.

mount --bind /old/dir /new/dir